# Detect array_key_exists called on object

Tags: php, phpstorm, deprecated, static-analysis

Since I want to move my codebase to PHP 7.4, it is important to refactor calls of `array_key_exists` since it now cannot use an object as a second parameter (`array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated`).

How can I go about detecting uses of this function with this specific parameter type? Is there any way I can achieve that in say PhpStorm or via static analysis?

This does not have to apply to only `array_key_exists`, any way of finding method usages based on parameter type would work.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that there's an inspection for that in PHPStorm. It's in [PHP - Parameter Type](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-parameter-type.html). I went ahead and created an inspection profile with only this inspection checked. Now it's only a matter of finding the right errors that pertain to `array_key_exists`.

Comment: FYI/in case if you did not know: 1) If you know the inspection name then you may use `Code | Analyze Code | Run Inspection by Name...` instead of making a separate Profile. 2) There is SSR (Structural Search & Replace) -- can be run as an ad-hoc search (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/structural-search-and-replace.html) or as an Inspection (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | Structural search`) -- might be used for such cases.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks, I had no idea this functionality existed, it's amazing.